# Why is $S \cup U$ not a subspace of $M$, where $M$ is the space of all 3x3 matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was finishing up Gilbert Strang's lecture on Linear Algebra (Lecture 11 of MIT OCW) in which he discussed matrix spaces. There was a question posed which has been described in the title for which I have trouble wrapping my head around the explanation. This is the explanation provided (lifted from the lecture summary notes):

*Is $S \cup U$, the set of 3 by 3 matrices which are either symmetric or upper
triangular, a subspace of $M$? No. This is like taking two lines in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and asking
if together they form a subspace; we have to fill in between them.*

I can't seem to derive any intuitive understanding from this explanation. The only visualization I have in my head is that $S$ and $U$ are each 6-dimensional subspaces of $M$. Hence this implies that their basis vectors each span a subspace of $\mathbb{R^6}$ in $M$. However, their union i.e. the possible linear combinations of basis vectors for $S \cup U$ are not necessarily a subset of the basis vectors of $M$. Hence, $S \cup U$ is not a subspace of $M$.

Is this way of thinking accurate? I do not have any background experience in Linear Algebra, hence any more intuitive ways of thinking about this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I assume $S$ is the set of symmetric and $U$ is the set of upper triangular...  Tell me... if you have some specific symmetric matrix and some specific upper triangular... is their sum necessarily going to be symmetric?  Is it necessarily going to be upper triangular?  Might it be neither?

Comment: The dimensions of $S$ and $U$ are completely irrelevant here.

Comment: As an aside, don't use the self-learning tag for questions about the content of what you are studying in maths.  That tag is meant for questions about pedagogy, the art of learning on your own, e.g. good study habits and self administering exams and homework.

Comment: Hi there, for the first question, this was similarly addressed in the lecture where he mentioned that the sum of every symmetric matrix and every upper triangular matrix would give every 3x3 matrix (of which not all are necessarily symmetric or upper triangular). Sorry, but I have trouble wrapping my head around this idea too. Based on one set of basis vectors provided, I can see how this may be the case. However, is this generalizable to other non-symmetric or non-upper triangular matrices as well?

Comment: And I've noted your point on the use of tags! Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: With regards to your question in the comments, as alluded to in the cited passage intuition can often be built relatively easily using specifically $\Bbb R^n$ as your space.  We can quickly picture and visualize $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$, and although we might not be able to *draw* higher, we can certainly gain intuition about higher $n$.  To translate the intuition of $\Bbb R^n$ to your matrix space, note that $\mathcal{M}_{3\times 3}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^9$, seen by just rearranging and stacking all of the entries in a single column rather than three columns.